# Can I connect two computers to one monitor, with one connected via VGA and the other via DVI?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, vga, dvi, windows-98

Is it possible to connect two computers to one monitor?

- The monitor is a Samsung S24B150BL (24 inch).
- No 1 Computer is running Windows 7 64-bit, to be connected via DVI.
- No 2 Computer is running Windows 98 SE, to be connected via VGA.

To eliminate the need for a KVM switch, only one computer will be running at a time.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect *and run* both computers at the same time.

All you need to do in order to switch between displaying Computer #1 and Computer #2 is to push the ["input" button](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/421125/Samsung-S24b150bl-User-Manual.html?page=21#manual) on the front of the monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not personally familiar with the Samsung S24B150BL, but I do know that some monitors will accept both DVI and VGA inputs (my Dell U2410s do this).

As long as you're not running both computers at the same time (which you stated in your question text), you're right that you won't need a KVM switch to get this working.  Just make sure that you give the monitor time to either "go to sleep" or start searching for an input signal after you turn one computer off *before* turning on the other computer.  That gives the monitor the best chance to detect the new video signal and display it correctly.

Comment: Thanks All,
As mentioned the Monitor does have a Dedicated Monitor Switch which enables me to switch between either analog or DVI.
I will connect the two over the next few days and let you all know the outcome.
Again many thanks for your input.
Regards 
Paul Clarke

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can.

I have a monitor with a DVI, a VGA and an HDMI port and I've connected two computers to the first two ports and a PS3 to the HDMI port. When I need to change, I simply switch between the devices using the dedicated monitor button.